# Como usar limit 1,1 en una consulta laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Esta consulta me devuelve el penultimo registro

```
SELECT * from publicaciones INNER JOIN img_publicaciones where publicaciones.id = img_publicaciones.publicaciones_id ORDER BY publicaciones.id DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Como le hago para convertirla y ser usada en laravel? 
Tengo esto:

```
$penultimo= DB::table('publicaciones')
        ->join('img_publicaciones', 'publicaciones.id', '=', 'img_publicaciones.publicaciones_id')
        ->whereColumn([['publicaciones.id', '=', 'img_publicaciones.publicaciones_id',]])
        ->orderByDesc('publicaciones.id')
        ->take(1,1)
        ->get();

$view->with(['penultimo' => $penultimo]);
```

Lo que me devuelve como resultado hasta ahora es el ultimo registro, no el penúltimo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente deberás usar los 2 siguientes métodos:

- skip
- take

De modo que un:

```
LIMIT 1, 1
```

Te quedaría así:

```
......skip(1)->take(1)
```

Así pues comoe estás ordenando de forma descedente le indicarías: omite un registro y toma el siguiente (solo 1 de ellos)

O como también puedes comprobar en el enlace propuesto, se disponen de los métodos:

- LIMIT
- OFFSET

Donde para la consulta quedaría:

```
.........offset(1)->limit(1)
```

**Fuentes consultadas**

- [skip y take](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)